# Let $A \in M_n $ be rank 1 PSD; $B = Q^{-\frac{1}{2}} A Q^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, $Q$ is PD. Then can be $B$ be unitarily diagonalized?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_n$ be rank one positive semidefinite (PSD) matrix, and the matrix $A$ can be unitarily diagonalised such that $A = U \Lambda U^*$ (eigenvalue decomposition EVD) where $U^*U=UU^* = I$.

For a given $Q$ symmetric positive definite (PD) matrix, and 
$$B = Q^{-\frac{1}{2}} A Q^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ is also positive semidefinite and rank-one.

Then can $B$ be unitarily diagonlized?

---

Attempt

\begin{align}
B 
&= Q^{-\frac{1}{2}} A Q^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= Q^{-\frac{1}{2}} U \Lambda U^* Q^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
\end{align}

Then I don't know whether $B = V \Sigma V^*$ be unitarily diagonalised? Because $VV^* = Q^{-1}  \neq V^*V = U^* Q^{-1} U \neq I$ unless $Q = I$. I am confused. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is symmetric since
$$
B^*=(Q^{-1/2}AQ^{-1/2})^*=(Q^{-1/2})^*A^*(Q^{-1/2})^*=Q^{-1/2}AQ^{-1/2}
$$
since $Q^{-1/2}$ and $A$ are symmetric. Hence, $B$ is unitarily diagonalisable.

$Q^{-1/2}$ is symmetric since, if $Q=U^*DU$, where $U$ is unitary and $D$ diagonal with positive elements, then $Q^{-1/2}=U^*D^{-1/2}U$.

Finally, 
$$
\text{rank}(B)=\text{rank}(A)=1,
$$
since $Q^{-1/2}$ is invertible.